# Restlet Post Request does not provide JSON data passed

Tags: java, api, restlet, restlet-2.0

I am using Restlet 2.1.2 and am having an unusual problem of my request Representation text being null. I have looked at the forums and read that the entity is transient and will be destroyed if not cached correctly but while I have a guard providing security, it doesn't touch the entity as I know of. More interestingly, for one route /authenticate, which merely checks if the user can be authenticated, can get the entity text, a JSON object. However when the code for /account/create is run, both post requests using @Post("json:json"), I can not get the JSON data sent. Below I've added my code and the sample curl statements I'm issuing. for the results see the AuthenticationResource and Account Resource classes.

```
public class Executable{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Component com = new Component();
        com.getServers().add( Protocol.HTTP,  8182 );
        com.getDefaultHost().attach( "/myapi", new RoutingApp() );
        com.start();  
    }
}

public class RoutingApp extends Application {

    public RoutingApp() {
        super();
    }

    @Override  
    public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() { 

        Context context = getContext();
        Router router = new Router(context);

        router.attach( "/account/create", AccountResource.class );
        router.attach( "/authenticate", AuthenticationResource.class );

        ChallengeAuthenticator authenticator = new ChallengeAuthenticator( 
                context, ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "myapi" );

        MySecretVerifier verifier = new MySecretVerifier();
        MyEnroler enroler = new MyEnroler();
        authenticator.setVerifier( verifier );
        authenticator.setEnroler( enroler );

        MyAuthorizer authorizer = new MyAuthorizer();
        authorizer.setNext( router );

        authenticator.setNext( authorizer );

        return authenticator; 
    }
}

public class MySecretVerifier extends SecretVerifier {

    @Override
    public int verify( String identifier, char[] secret ) {

       [... Get User by identifier ...]

       if( [... Check User Secret ...] ) {
           Request request = Request.getCurrent();
           request.getAttributes().put( "currentUser", user );
           return SecretVerifier.RESULT_VALID;
       } else {
           return SecretVerifier.RESULT_INVALID;
       }
    }
}

public class MyEnroler implements Enroler {

    @Override
    public void enrole(ClientInfo ci) {

        Request request = Request.getCurrent();
        User user = (User) request.getAttributes().get( "currentUser" );

        if( null != user ) {

            [... Get User Roles ...]

            for( [... Each Role ...] ) {
                Role role = newRole( r.name, "" );
                ci.getRoles().add( role );
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyAuthorizer extends Authorizer {

    @Override
    protected boolean authorize( Request request, Response response ) {

        ClientInfo info = request.getClientInfo();
        Method method = request.getMethod();
        User user = (User) request.getAttributes().get( "currentUser" );
        String uri = request.getResourceRef().getRemainingPart( true, false );
        List<Role> userRoles = info.getRoles();

        boolean authorized = false;

        if( [... Check if User is Authorized ...] ) {
            request.getAttributes().putAll( [... add some properties from a HashMap ...] );
            authorized = false;
        }

        return authorized;
    }
}

public class AuthenticationResource extends ServerResource {

    @Post("json:json")
    @Override
    public String performPost(Representation entity) {

        Request request = Request.getCurrent();

        request.getEntityAsText();     //returns { "id" : "larry", "secret" : "test" }
        request.getEntity().getText(); //returns null
        entity.toString();                  //returns [application/json]
        entity.getText();                  //returns null
    }
}

public class AccountResource extends ServerResource {

    @Post("json:json")
    @Override
    public String performPost( Representation entity ) {

        Request request = Request.getCurrent();

        request.getEntityAsText();     //returns null
        request.getEntity().getText(); //returns null
        entity.toString();                  //returns [application/json]
        entity.getText();                   //returns null
    }
}
```

My CURL statements are as follows:

```
curl -i --user larry:test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "id" : "larry", "secret" : "test" }' http://localhost:8182/myapi/account/create
curl -i --user larry:test -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "id" : "larry", "secret" : "test" }' http://localhost:8182/myapi/authenticate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others run into a similar issue, it was actually the name of the class "AccountResource" that was the issue. I'm not sure why but I could only assume that it had something to do with an AccountResource interface that was built into Restlet that was causing the issue.